# Creating a endless centered carousel control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a endless, centered carousel in WPF like in this concept image. The current solution I've come up with is using a listbox, loading all images into a ObservableCollection and then modifying it to create the illusion of movement.

[image]

I have two issues with this solution. First I can't seem to center it. The listbox is aligned to the left with no way of getting it to overflow on both sides. Regardless of the size of my window it should always show one console in the middle, one on each sides and a half one to indicate that there's more to choose from.

The second issue is not as important, but I'm looking for a proper way of doing this that may allow a more fluent transition between selections later on.

This is my current code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SystemMenu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="left" Height="20" Click="Left_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <Button Content="right" Height="20" Click="Right_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

    <ListBox x:Name="LoopPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleData}" SelectedIndex="3" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    ObservableCollection<string> sampleData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> SampleData
    {
        get
        {
            if (sampleData.Count <= 0)
            {
                sampleData.Add(@"Nintendo 64.png");
                sampleData.Add(@"Nintendo Famicom.png");
                sampleData.Add(@"Super Nintendo Entertainment System.png");
                sampleData.Add(@"Nintendo Entertainment System.png");
                sampleData.Add(@"Sony PlayStation.png");
            }
            return sampleData;
        }
    }

    private void Right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstItem = SampleData.First();
        SampleData.Remove(firstItem);
        SampleData.Insert(SampleData.Count, firstItem);
    }

    private void Left_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lastItem = SampleData.Last();
        SampleData.Remove(lastItem);
        SampleData.Insert(0, lastItem);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I found the following extension solving the issue I had with centering the listbox. Calling LoopPanel.ScrollToCenterOfView(sampleData[2]); seems to do the trick of centering the images... Any idea now on how to animate the transition? :)

```
 public static class ItemsControlExtensions
    {
        public static void ScrollToCenterOfView(this ItemsControl itemsControl, object item)
        {
            // Scroll immediately if possible
            if (!itemsControl.TryScrollToCenterOfView(item))
            {
                // Otherwise wait until everything is loaded, then scroll
                if (itemsControl is ListBox) ((ListBox)itemsControl).ScrollIntoView(item);
                itemsControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
                {
                    itemsControl.TryScrollToCenterOfView(item);
                }));
            }
        }

        private static bool TryScrollToCenterOfView(this ItemsControl itemsControl, object item)
        {
            // Find the container
            var container = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as UIElement;
            if (container == null) return false;

            // Find the ScrollContentPresenter
            ScrollContentPresenter presenter = null;
            for (Visual vis = container; vis != null && vis != itemsControl; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
                if ((presenter = vis as ScrollContentPresenter) != null)
                    break;
            if (presenter == null) return false;

            // Find the IScrollInfo
            var scrollInfo =
                !presenter.CanContentScroll ? presenter :
                presenter.Content as IScrollInfo ??
                FirstVisualChild(presenter.Content as ItemsPresenter) as IScrollInfo ??
                presenter;

            // Compute the center point of the container relative to the scrollInfo
            Size size = container.RenderSize;
            Point center = container.TransformToAncestor((Visual)scrollInfo).Transform(new Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2));
            center.Y += scrollInfo.VerticalOffset;
            center.X += scrollInfo.HorizontalOffset;

            // Adjust for logical scrolling
            if (scrollInfo is StackPanel || scrollInfo is VirtualizingStackPanel)
            {
                double logicalCenter = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container) + 0.5;
                Orientation orientation = scrollInfo is StackPanel ? ((StackPanel)scrollInfo).Orientation : ((VirtualizingStackPanel)scrollInfo).Orientation;
                if (orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                    center.X = logicalCenter;
                else
                    center.Y = logicalCenter;
            }

            // Scroll the center of the container to the center of the viewport
            if (scrollInfo.CanVerticallyScroll) scrollInfo.SetVerticalOffset(CenteringOffset(center.Y, scrollInfo.ViewportHeight, scrollInfo.ExtentHeight));
            if (scrollInfo.CanHorizontallyScroll) scrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(CenteringOffset(center.X, scrollInfo.ViewportWidth, scrollInfo.ExtentWidth));
            return true;
        }

        private static double CenteringOffset(double center, double viewport, double extent)
        {
            return Math.Min(extent - viewport, Math.Max(0, center - viewport / 2));
        }
        private static DependencyObject FirstVisualChild(Visual visual)
        {
            if (visual == null) return null;
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual) == 0) return null;
            return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would take a look at sources of PivotControl similar endless scrolling control in Windows Phone to see how they did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I would do it how you're doing it. I.e. adding and removing items in a ListBox. Doesn't give you enough control on the positioning and you won't be able to do smooth animations of it rotating which with that kind of UI, I think that would be kind of expected :).

I'd probably have a Canvas instead with ClipToBounds=true. Then just calculate the positions, you aren't doing a rounded carousel, so positions are trivial and there is no zooming.

Lets say your images are all 100 x 100. So item0 will be @ -50,0, item1 @ 50,0 (well, technically probably 75,0 or whatever because you'd want some spacing between them, but you get the idea), etc. Because you are calculating the positions and have them absolute against the Canvas, the ClipToBound=true will clip the two on either end and you'll be able to animate the rotation.

Comment: I'm torn on this answer. It's better graphically, but you'll lose *a lot* of functionality without some kind of premade scrollable/selectable/loadable collection container - ItemsSource, SelectedItem, SelectedIndex, etc. Have you any suggestions on how these would be implemented using your approach?

Comment: But its that functionality that's getting in your way. A pre-built scroller like a ListBox or whatever is going to expect the items to remain in the same place relative to each other. It also is going to be a doozy to get the wrapping to work as a scroller expects you to scroll from 0 to X and from X to 0. Not in a circular fashion. You would have to re-implement the scrolling to get the cool animations going anyways. If you want scroll arrows on the sides, you can make some arrows on a RepeatButton. Don't think you need SelectedIndex. SelectedItem would just be the image you click on.

Comment: PART #2... make each image on top of a transparent grid so you don't have to click on the actual image itself, but rather on the surrounding square. I.e. if you had a circle, unless you had the transparent grid background, you'd have to click on the actual circle and you wouldn't be able to click in the corners. You can encapsulate everything fairly easily in a custom control. I think it'll be way harder to work around all the built in functionality then to implement the animated scrolling, wrapping, etc. and shoe horn it into a ListBox.

Comment: PART #3: LOL.. finally, I don't think its very feasible to get the ListBox to show a partial item at the left as it expects item 0 to start at pixel 0. You can try put a ListBox in a Grid with ClipToBounds=True and set the margin of the ListBox to -50 and see if that's to your liking. That'll clip the left item in half, but you'd never have a full item on the left and the scroll bar would also be clipped. Personally with that UI, I'd do an overlay scroll arrow anyways. A standard scrollbar would look odd.

Comment: Do you mean similar to this example? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042371/how-to-create-an-automatic-animated-carousel-cyling-images-using-c-sharp-or-xaml

I'll give it a try, but if I'm not using a listbox or similar... how can I then get the current selected item?

Comment: All selecting an item is, is clicking on it. So subscribe to Image.Click or the transparent Grid.Click and that's your selected item.

Comment: Oh, that might be an issue(?).
I don't intend to use a mouse, but a joystick in order to navigate...

Comment: Oh... so I'd probably have the center one "selected" by default. Joystick to the left and select the previous item, joystick to the right and select the next item and obviously wrap at the ends.

Comment: "...you aren't doing a rounded carousel..."
Maybe I misunderstood or did not elaborate my issue well enough.. but I think about having a endless carousel that never ends (looping items).

I'm  not sure if I like this solution. I feel I loose control over the items and "hard code" more then I want to in terms of image size and positions... No offend, but I agree more with @goobering, but without any good alternative to your solution. Thanks for all the input!